# Parse-Server with Solr Search Engine?

Tags: solr, search-engine, parse-server

I want to implement the parse-server search engine, I tried looking on different links and find the "full tax search", partial and case sensitive search.

I did not find any implementation with Solr Search Engine, anyone have any docs or links to implement that?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems [full text search in parse is a very recent feature](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3747), that is implemented across MongoDB and (possibly) PostgreSQL with their built-in full text search. The previous solution was to replicate mongodb to Elasticsearch or Solr, which you can do in the usual way.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the response, do you have any doc link for the Elastic or Solr Search?

Comment: Those examples are manual implementations - they're not part of parse-server itself (and the manual Elasticsearch implementation is mentioned in the linked thread and based on Mongoose)

Comment: Yes, I just saw that, so what I understand, it will not going to work directly with the parse-server, I need to create the separate model for the classes (from Parse Collections) in Elastic Search using mongoose and also I need to create the different API endpoints to search in the specific collection. let me know if this is what I need to implement. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know from my limited experience with an old version of parse-server, yes. I didn't find any other changes (and seeing as this is a rather recent change to allow full text search at all) to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh. I really appreciate your thoughts.